# take a conditional mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a data set like this:

[image]

I want to take the mean of LCR in each year for WFR=1 and WFR=0 separately, for example in 2018 I have 4 WFR=0 so take the mean of LCR for it and for WFR=1 I have just one. any idea? thanks

Comment: can you paste the data as text and format as code? Makes it hard to copy paste with images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby by year and WFR. This will create every combination that exists in your dataset. If all conditions are not in your dataframe you can create a base dataframe with all conditions and merge with it.

```
df = data_new4.groupby(['CLOSDATE_year', 'WFR'])['LCR'].mean()
```

to plot the data you can use the seaborn library.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df, hue='WFR', x='CLOSDATE_year', y='LCR')
```

Comment: how can I plot these LCR(mean of LCR) according to the WFR(0 or 1) in different years? I mean 2 line graph in one plot

Comment: I added the code for you to be able to plot the data. Can you please upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `groupby`:

```
>>> data.groupby(["CLOSDATE_year", "WFR"])["LCR"].mean()

CLOSDATE_year  WFR
2011           1      268.750000
2012           1      235.533333
2018           0      192.775000
               1      186.000000
Name: LCR, dtype: float64
```

Comment: can I add a name for the mean of LCR there? because the column does not have the name

Comment: This returns a series called LCR. Look at the last line of the output. If you want a DataFrame, you can do `data.groupby(["CLOSDATE_year", "WFR"])["LCR"].mean().reset_index()`